# スワイプ時にはボタンを反応させないようにしたい

Tags: swift, ios

### やりたいこと

iOSアプリに、Twitterのタイムラインのような縦方向にスクロールするUIを実装しています。

縦スワイプで縦にスクロールさせようとした際に、UI上のボタンの領域をスワイプさせてしまうと、スクロールせずボタンのタップイベントが発火してしまいます。(Twitterを例にとると、スクロールさせようとすると、リツイート等のボタンを押してしまう状態です）

スワイプとタップを判別して、スワイプの場合はボタンのイベントを発火させないよい方法はないでしょうか？

### 環境

・Swift 3
・iOS 8.0以上

Answer (score 0):

タップのイベントはどのアクションでとっていますか？
たぶんこの動作をしているということは、ボタンのTouchDownのイベントでボタンの処理を行っているのだと思います。
TouchUpInsideのイベントで処理を行うようにすると解決すると思います。
いかがでしょうか？

もしよろしければ、ボタン部分のコードを見せていただけるとより詳しい回答ができるかもしれません。

Comment: @user17014コメントありがとうございます。現状ですが、以下のようなコードで実装しております。

let gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.0
gesture.allowableMovement = 10.0

Comment: ボタンのタップ部分のコードを見せてもらってもいいですか？ボタンのどのイベントで処理を発火させていますか？ストーリーボードを使われている場合は、つなげている「Sent Events」を教えてください。

Comment: @mori 他の閲覧者にも分かるように追加情報はコメントではなく質問文に追記してください。"編集"ボタンから編集が可能です。